# Can the center move the football before the snap?

Tags: rules, american-football

In high school football, can the center in football move the ball on the ground before snapping it?

Comment: @leDominatre removing "high school" made this question more broad as high school, college, and pro football leagues may have different rules on the matter.

Answer (score 3):

> In high school football, can the center in football move the ball on the ground before snapping it?

No. Adjustment appears to be legal when the ball is lifted for lateral rotation*, but nothing else. Once this adjustment is completed, any further adjustment is illegal†.

*Rule 7, Section 1, Article 2 of the [2014 NFHS Rules (page 58)](http://www.sdcfoa.org/wp-content/uploads/NFHS_Rules.pdf) (the most recent I can find) states:

> The snapper may lift the ball for lateral rotation but may not rotate end-for-end or change the location or fail to keep the long axis of the ball at right angles to the line of scrimmage.

†Rule 7, Section 1, Article 3, d states:

> Following the ready-for-play and after touching the ball, the snapper shall not:
>
> - Following adjustment, lift or **move** the ball other than in a legal snap.

Comment: Those rules have remained exactly the same in the 2016 and 2015 NFHS Football Rules Books, including the section and article numbers.